# SMS Commands to Twilio Super SIM

Tags: postman

How do I setup Postman to send SMS commands to a Twilio Super SIM? I was able to do it for Programmable Wireless but having a bit of trouble for Super SIMS.

Answer (score 1):

There is my setup

**METHOD:** POST
**URL:** https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/SmsCommands

**Authorization**

```
use: Basic Auth
USERNAME: AccountSid
PASSWORD: AuthToken
```

**Body**

```
use x-www-form-urlencoded
Payload: your sms command
Sid: your sim card id
```